# Error in printing the real price and currency "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print the real price of bitcoins using python, but when extracting the name of the currency and its amount, I get an error of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Here is the code I used:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-CAD/buy"
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BS(data.text, 'html.parser')
ans = soup.find("amount", class_="currency").text
```

in the last line, it gives me an error of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`
How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you downloaded that page and looked at it yourself?  It doesn't return HTML at all.  It returns JSON.  You don't need BeautifulSoup.

```
url = "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/ETH-CAD/buy"
data = requests.get(url)
ans = json.loads(data.text)
```

Comment: but when I run the command `soup = BS(data.text, 'html.parser')` , it gives me the information inside that file !

Comment: It's JSON.  You use `ans = json.loads( data.text )`.

Comment: I got it similar to the old method, it's  like this `'data': {'base': 'ETH', 'currency': 'CAD', 'amount': '3370.65'}}` ... So I am asking about  how I can only print the  amount??  Thank you sir

Comment: Forgive me for getting sarcastic, but you should have been able to figure this out.  It's a simple Python dictionary.   You access it like any Python dictionary.  `data['data']['amount']`.