# how can I print a real number of such bitcoins and its name from web-page in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage which include a price of a bitcoins, for example this page, https://www.coinbase.com/price/keep3rv1 , I want to print the recent price of this bitcoin with specific currency (for example USD), here is what I did:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.coinbase.com/price/keep3rv1')
soup = BS(data.text, 'html.parser')
ans = soup.find("amount", class_="currency").text
```

The two last lines of the above code, I am not sure about them, but they don't run correctly. I need to know  how to  extract the price of the above example bitcoin in USD.

NP: When using the API of the coins, I cannot deal with the mentioned coin because it's not supported by coinsbase. In other words, I cannot use the command `data = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/kp3r-USD/buy')` since it's not supported by coinbase.  On the other hand, I can easily use this way with other supported coins by coinsbase, for example btc, which can be gotten as following `data = requests.get('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/btc-USD/buy')`. For that, I've opened a new question here.
It means, the question answered here [Error in printing the real price and currency "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290431/error-in-printing-the-real-price-and-currency-attributeerror-nonetype-object?noredirect=1&lq=1)  is not the same ! , it's different !

Comment: Use their API instead of trying to scrape their web pages.

Comment: @Selcuk  how can I do it please ? I am newbie in python, could you please provide an example?

Comment: @HedgeHog , this coins I mentioned is not supported by coinbase, but that I cannot use that method !!

Comment: It's the same code with the same error and the same explanation. I fail to see how this is different. Only the URL is different, but that does not change the question itself. Also note that "_they don't run correctly_" is not a proper problem description. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953).

Answer (score -1):

errors: you need urls in string and also write print function and at the end remove text from last line

first you need to find that will have the price. after that process for every tag till you find the price and that is the key

it will done without bs4 using only request as

```py
import request
data = requests.get(https://www.coinbase.com/price/keep3rv1)

# loop for the span tag
# in each line of data
# when you get all the span tag search for the  'AssetChartAmount__Number-sc-1b4douf-1 foyTCz' class

# this will work for this page if you need every class then you need to change search algorithms not need for bs4
```

Comment: but this code you provided can't print what I want, please recheck it.

Comment: Even if I used that, that didn't print the price and currency of the mentioned coins.

Comment: you need code ? i cant give you the perfect running code but give you some help in last line  of your code it remove the text and in round brackets is first is the tag and second is the class of the tag. means you need a class name and tag name in order to to so. and thats i give in the code class and tage is span go and research on that topic. don't expect another person will write full code for you

Comment: I don't need the code, but what's supposed to replace the text and class in the last line?

Answer (score -1):

this is the code changes

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.coinbase.com/price/keep3rv1')
soup = BS(data.text, 'html.parser')
ans = soup.find("amount", class_="currency")
# here the amount is the thing that the search in page any name of page 
# and after that you'll need to add the class 
print(ans)
```

example :

website have have the price instead of amount and the class name if that consider multiple time , class could be anything depends on developer

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.coinbase.com/price/keep3rv1')
soup = BS(data.text, 'html.parser')
ans = soup.find("price", class_="whataver_on_that")
print(ans)
```

Comment: after all that it will not gonne work on this thing as @Selcuk  says that use api on this kind of the website

Comment: I know what you mean, but I have mentioned above that coins is not supported by coinbase, so that I cannot use the api to get its updated price !!  for that I have tried using the code I provided.